# My newly installed ubuntu software is not detecting sdcard.

Tags: sd-card

just switched from Windows 10 to ubuntu. it is not recognizing sd and and I'm very confused on every site I looked into. so please in layman terms. can someone help

Comment: please  [edit] your question with version of Ubuntu for others to better help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install "flashrom" from the software center this may support your sdcards. Simply Open the software center and search flashrom. 
[image]

Comment: will try tomorrow, and respond back, thank you! !!

Comment: any solutions for bluetooth printer? it will not allow me to turn the connection on and print but the device (hp100) is recognized as device

Comment: Np please remember to click the ChecK MarK!! And yes, hplip works well with blue-tooth printers software center & search hiplip (make sure extra packages are check at the bottom ;)